# Prism.StoreApps.Windows.dll error in universal phone app project

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, prism, win-universal-app

I have created a Universal Windows solution which has Windows ,Phone and Shared projects. Later I installed Prism 6 and Prism.StoreApps Nuget pakcages in my solution.

Though my Windows project builds successfully the phone project always fails with the below error.

```
Error 2 Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Windows, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. MyProj.WindowsPhone

Error 1 Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Windows.dll'\MyProj\MyProj.WindowsPhone\MyProj.WindowsPhone.csproj
```

========================================================================

I am building my project with Configuration as "Active(Debug)"  and  Platform as "AnyCPU" . I tried with other options of Platform which are x86,x64 and ARM but the results is same.

Comment: Did you add the Nuget packages to both projects?   The error message says you didn't.

Comment: Yes, I did add and I am using the libraries from the Prism namespace in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

We have not release NuGet packages for our UWP support yet.  Prism.Store and Prism 6 are not compatible.